# MSSQL trigger does not see changes of updated row in different table in same transaction

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions

Lets say we have three tables in MSSQL database, A, B and C.

I have a trigger on A after update. This trigger takes some values from B and inserts them into C.

The transaction performs operations in following order:

1. Begin transaction.
2. Insert a record into table B.
3. Update previously inserted (in step 2) record in table B.
4. Update table A (trigger is triggered).
5. Trigger inserts into table C some values from inserted in step 2 row.
6. End of transaction.

The problem is, that values inserted into table C based on the row in table B are only the values from right after the B record was inserted, and do not contain the changes made during the updated operation.

Why?

Trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER ON [dbo].[A] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO C (SOME_TEXT_VALUE) SELECT SOME_TEXT_VALUE FROM B;
END
GO
```

Comment: Please share you trigger code

Comment: I'd say this is a deadborn solution. Trigger that fires another trigger which is supposed to return to previous table, modify records updated in first step and fire once more first trigger which is supposed in second run to work differently and insert something in third table...

Comment: @HoneyBadger I've added the code

Comment: @IvanStarostin There is only one trigger and it is triggered only once. The steps 1-6 just show what happens in the whole db transaction. The only trigger is fired after 4th step.

Comment: Any trigger that fails to reference `inserted` or `deleted` is usually considered to be broken. However, by keeping everything so *abstract* in your question, it's difficult to know what you're trying to achieve, and so be able to suggest how things could be fixed.